# Loading dbf Foxpro file from Excel VBA Project

Tags: excel, vba, visual-foxpro, dbf

I’m trying to load a dbf file generated from Foxpro7 into Excel (programmatically), I don’t want to use any export/import mechanisms because the objective is to carry out this transparently for the user. Is there any way of doing this using VBA without using any external tool and compatible for x86 and x64 platforms? 
Thanks.

Comment: The very short answer is `Yes`. See [this](https://myengineeringworld.net/2013/09/read-dbf-files-using-vba.html)

Comment: Dbf and Foxpro dbf are similar but different, that code works for conventional dbase file but not for dbf Foxpro generated, that’s why I’m asking… thanks

Comment: Have you considered just changing the connection string and give it a try? See if  [Visual FoxPro connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro/) helps.

Comment: Well, the have read that the VFP OLE DB Provider is not compatible with x64, I have to try with ODBC to see results. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is NO, but a long answer might be YES.  You can't do that using official VFP drivers, but with maybe using a driver like Sybase ADS (local server mode was for free). However, the easier way is to do that from VFP instead. From VFP you could save to an ADO stream which you could open from 64 bits Excel also. You could do that from Excel too, if you create an addin that would read using 32 bit connection, save to a ADO stream (or a recordset).